# Extract variable-length string using an SQL query

Tags: sql-server, database

I have an SQL database column called "Details" that always follows the pattern

```
AAA (BBB, DD-MM-YYYY, CCC);
```

where A, B, and C may be any length. My query to extract BBB is

```
SELECT    
[Number]=substring([Details], patindex('% (%', [Details])+2,patindex('% (%, %',[Details]))
FROM tablename
```

However, I'm having issues getting the query to stop at the right spot. It returns eight characters each time, counting from the start of BBB. I suspect it's my usage of the second PATINDEX function in the query that's affecting this, however I'm not sure what functions or arguments I can use in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
select substring(
    details, 
    charindex('(', details) + 1, 
    charindex(',', details) - charindex('(', details) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combo of `PARSENAME` and `CHARINDEX` to find the string:

```
SELECT RIGHT(PARSENAME(REPLACE([Details],',','.'),3),CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE([Details],',','.'),3)))-1)
```